# org.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to Serializable_JSONObject

Tags: java, casting

[image]I'm receiving the following error while casting

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to NCRB_GUIs.DeviceGroupManager.FetcherForms.Serializable_JSONObject
```

My Serializable_JSONObject is defined as:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.json.JSONObject;
public class Serializable_JSONObject extends JSONObject implements Serializable{}
```

I am unsure why I am getting this error. Here is the code where the exception is thrown...

```
    @Override
    public ReturnInterface<Serializable_JSONObject> call() throws Exception {
        CredentialInterface ci = (CredentialInterface) this.taskDeployInterface;
        JSONObject READ_NO_VALIDATION = WebGet.READ_NO_VALIDATION(ci.getUser(), ci.getPassword(), new URL(ci.getHost()));
        Serializable_JSONObject o = (Serializable_JSONObject) READ_NO_VALIDATION;//Error thrown here
        this.returnItem = o;
        return this;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post the code where the exception occurs?

Comment: Without code, a bit hard to help you

Comment: Added the throwing code.

Comment: You can cast Serializable_JSONOBject to JSONObject.

You can't cast JSONObject to Serializable_JSONOBject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this issue is occurring as `WebGet.READ_NO_VALIDATION(ci.getUser(), ci.getPassword(), new URL(ci.getHost()));` line of code retruns a object of `JsonObject` not the `Serializable_JSONObject` and as `Serializable_JSONObject` is a sub class of `JsonObject` you can't cast JosnObject's object to sub class object. You can debug that READ_NO_VALIDATION is object of  which class by `READ_NO_VALIDATION.getClass()`.

Comment: If you look at the definition of Serializable_JSONObject, you will see it is a simple extension of JSONObject which implements serializable. It should be able to be cast.

Comment: I have updated the code as above. The error is thrown at the cast.

Comment: To cast an object to Serializable_JSONObject class object, it must need to be the object of Serialiezable_JSONObject or it's subsclass object. You can't cast superclass object to subclass.

Comment: Can you please just print the class of that object using : `System.out.println(READ_NO_VALIDATION.getClass());`

Comment: You are right. What would be the easiest way to make this conversion?

Comment: Class= class org.json.JSONObject
[ProgressBarHelper]done!
Jun 06, 2018 1:29:37 PM org.openide.util.Exceptions printStackTrace
SEVERE: null
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to NCRB_GUIs.DeviceGroupManager.FetcherForms.Serializable_JSONObject
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)

Comment: For that, I need more information and the context for that. Need to look at the definition of `WebGet#READ_NO_VALIDATION()`

Comment: This is based off  apache's org.json. return XML.toJSONObject(sb.toString());

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172618/discussion-between-amit-bera-and-jamie-snipes).

Comment: @JamieSnipes Not exactly. Please follow the link it may help you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20534862/how-to-efficiently-map-a-org-json-jsonobject-to-a-pojo