# print multi dimentional json array in java

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, list

My app fetches JSON response from server. The response string has multiple rows and columns. I need to print this in java.

Here is my JSON response :

```
[
  {
    "name": "name2",
    "id": "99",
    "email": "ad@e.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "zca",
    "id": "96",
    "email": "as2c2@d.d",
  }
]
```

this is java part :

```
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    String url = ServerConstants.BROWSE_URL;
    //String url = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2";

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException
        {
            if (response.isSuccessful())
            {
                final String myResponse = response.body().string();
                //System.out.println(Arrays.asList(new BundleFunctions().MakeArrayListFormJSON(myResponse)));
                bundle = new BundleFunctions().MakeBundleFromJSON(myResponse);
                //System.out.println("this is size ------- "+bundle.size());
                //System.out.println("this is response ------ "+myResponse);
                Browse.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        tv.setText(myResponse);

                        Set<String> keys = bundle.keySet();

                        for(String key : keys)
                        {
                            Object o = bundle.get(key);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

I need a print on each person like this in java :

(Person number is according to array index FCFS)

**Person 1 - Name : name2 , id : 99 , email : ad@e.com**

**Person 2 - Name : zca , id : 96 , email : as2c2@d.d**

Please show me the simplest way to do this

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your relevant code.

Comment: ok wait showing

Comment: Android has built in classes to handle JSON such as JSONArray and JSONObject. use them, then it is a simple matter of looping through the JSONarray

Comment: @Christopher please have a look. this method only get 1 row not the whole thing by Object o

Answer (score 1):

JSON is really clear, which is `Array` of `Objects` in your case `Person` object, create `Person` POJO class

**Person**

```
public class Person {

 private String name;

 private String id;

 private String email;

 // getters and setters

 }
```

Parse the above json to `List<Person>` and print each `Person` as you like them

Comment: [java updated] How can i do that ? if i use Object o , it only catches 1 row

Comment: show this `bundle = new BundleFunctions().MakeBundleFromJSON(myResponse);` bundle @NinjaStar

Comment: https://pastebin.com/naDgcuqs

Comment: That's not right approach, you need to parse Json String to `List<Person>` i believe you are using `json` library @NinjaStar

Comment: no i am not using library, but which one should i use?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20534862/how-to-efficiently-map-a-org-json-jsonobject-to-a-pojo

Answer (score 0):

Your example of JSON doesn't looks multi dimensional array. It's an array with bunch of objects into it. If this is for java, why not use jackson or GSon or library like that to obtain object in an array list! All you have to define is a POJO object with matching variable names with getters and setters.

Comment: can you show me an easy example please?

Comment: download GSon lib from google.
Take the object created by Deadpool, 

you can find reference : http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/gson.html