# What is the PubNub channel name for MtGox BTCUSD trade?

Tags: bitcoin, pubnub, mtgox

I'm looking at this: https://mtgox.com/api/2/stream/list_public?pretty And I only see one: `"trade.BTC": "dbf1dee9-4f2e-4a08-8cb7-748919a71b21"`

When trying to connect to it, I'm getting very odd trade data, which, when compared to what I see on BitcoinWisdom doesn't really correlate. Where do I find an actual channel for BTC/USD trade and also what are the addresses for other currencies trades?

Answer (score -1):

Its d5f06780-30a8-4a48-a2f8-7ed181b4a13f

Try the following in the PubNub dev console to see the messages on this channel
https://www.pubnub.com/console?sub=sub-c-50d56e1e-2fd9-11e3-a041-02ee2ddab7fe&pub=demo&channel=d5f06780-30a8-4a48-a2f8-7ed181b4a13f&origin=pubsub.pubnub.com&ssl=true

You can also check http://rtbitcoin.co/ (PubNub Bitcoin Exchange solution kit) for more info

Also check a related stackoverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547815/convenient-way-to-extract-data-from-the-mtgox-pubnub-json-api/20553315#20553315)